# Faking Iframe size so @media query is no applied

Tags: html, css, reactjs, iframe, media-queries

I have a website in which I can render a simple Html page on a route `localhost:3000/static` and a 3d scene on the normal route `localhost:3000/`. What I'm attempting to perform is, the media query transforms, which will only be applied if the route is `localhost:3000/static`, but not in the iframe. Because mobile the iframe (route: `localhost:3000/`) shows as it is on mobile, but I want it to show if it was on a deskop, without applying @medias.
Here is the css and how the page is being rendered in iframe:

```
.htmlScreen iframe {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 700px;
  border: none;
  background: #000;
}

 <Html
            transform
            prepend
            wrapperClass="htmlScreen"
            scale={0.35}
            distanceFactor={1.17}
            zIndexRange={[0, 0]}
          >
            <div
              onClick={(e) => {
                if (!isFocusOnHtml) e.preventDefault();
              }}
              onPointerEnter={(e) => {
                if (isFocusOnHtml) setIsPointerOnHtml(true);
              }}
              onPointerLeave={() => {
                if (isFocusOnHtml) setIsPointerOnHtml(false);
              }}
            >
              <iframe
                src="https://niltonsf.dev/static"
                title="myStaticWebsite"
                style={{ width: isMobile ? 1200 : 1500 }}
              />
            </div>
          </Html>
```

This is the @media:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 708px) {
  #root {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

As you can see on my 3d view, the background is being appplied, because I'm seeing this on mobile, but I don't want the media to be applied on this route, for the iframe.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a workaround on how to use media queries according to what you need or specific environments. This way I have made it, you can apply according to the size, environments, and any other variables you would like.
Basically what I am using is a hook from `usehooks-ts` library:

```
import { useMediaQuery } from "usehooks-ts";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Header() {
  const mediumDevices = useMediaQuery("(max-width: 768px)");
  const smallDevices = useMediaQuery("(max-width: 350px)");
```

With this, I can keep track of the media queries, and apply them as I want. "This looks the same as applying normal queries", yes it looks! Although you can add variables, for example, `isMobile` or `isSpecialUser`, etc, meaning, you can change the styling data according to the type of user, or mobile environment. In my case, I'm using `styled-components` to apply styles, and receive variables.

This is a piece of my component and a example on how I'm using it:

```
xport default function Header() {
  const [toggleMenu, setToggleMenu] = useState(false);

  const mediumDevices = useMediaQuery("(max-width: 768px)");
  const smallDevices = useMediaQuery("(max-width: 350px)");

  return (
    <HeaderCP mediumDevices={mediumDevices}>
      <Nav>
        <span className="nav_logo">Nilton A Schumacher F</span>

        <NavMenu
          smallDevices={smallDevices}
          mediumDevices={mediumDevices}
          toggleMenu={toggleMenu}
        >
          <Ul smallDevices={smallDevices} mediumDevices={mediumDevices}>
```

On my styles I'm applying them as the following:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

interface MediaQuery {
  mediumDevices?: boolean;
  smallDevices?: boolean;
  toggleMenu?: boolean;
}

export const HeaderCP = styled.div<MediaQuery>`
  ${(props) => {
    let finalStyles = ``;
    finalStyles += `
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: var(--z-fixed);
        background-color: var(--body-color);
    `;
    if (props.mediumDevices) {
      finalStyles += `        
        top: initial;
        bottom: 0;
      `;
    }
    return finalStyles;
  }}
`;

export const Nav = styled.nav.attrs({
  className: "container",
})`
  height: calc(var(--header-height) + 1.5rem);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 1rem;
`;

export const NavMenu = styled.div<MediaQuery>`
  ${(props) => {
    let finalStyles = ``;
    if (props.mediumDevices) {
      finalStyles += `
        position: fixed;
        bottom: ${props.toggleMenu ? 0 : `-100%`};
        left: 0;
        right: 0;        
        width: 100vw - 50px;
        background-color: var(--body-color);        
        padding: 2rem 1.5rem 4rem;        
        box-shadow: 0 -1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        border-radius: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0 0;
        transition: 0.3s;        
      `;
    }
    if (props.smallDevices) {
      finalStyles += `
        padding: 2rem 0.25rem 4rem;        
      `;
    }
    return finalStyles;
  }}
`;
```

This is just an example, I could add something like `isMobile`, `isSamsung`, `isApple`, etc. Meaning I can apply different styles to different devices.

EDIT: In my case, I'm using `Three.js`, and rendering an iFrame with another route from my website. This solution was the one I was expecting. The iframe is not applying the mobile media queries on the main route (3d route) although If I go to the static website route, the media query is applied!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you control the both iframe site and the normal site. Why not load the site in iframe with a query like `/?site=mobile` or `/?site=desktop` or something that fits you and you can apply that class to your `body` tag inside the iframe. You need to set the parameters in your css according to that class, so you can set the size according to that class.

Below vanilla JS code gets the query string and add applies to the body tag.

```js
// /?site=mobile
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let siteClass = params.get('site'); // 'mobile'

bodyTag = document.querySelector("body");
bodyTag.classList.add(siteClass)  // body now has 'mobile' class
```

Bonus: I wouldn't directly give query parameter to class, meaning I would do some checks and set some defaults but this is the gist of it.

Comment: But the issue is, how to add a mediaQuery to that component.

Comment: I didn't understand. You want to add media query to the component dynamically? Why would you need that? If you control both environments set the media query per specific class and then set the class name dynamically.

Comment: I have found a solution and posted an answer